# I have updated to anypoint 7.11.1 now getting error while running munit

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4, munit

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EA10025-BTSNA-MOBILITYBTSNA-main': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#6697d772' of type [org.mule.module.apikit.Router] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6697d772': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'EA10025-BTSNA-MOBILITYBTSNA-config' while setting bean property 'configuration'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'EA10025-BTSNA-MOBILITYBTSNA-config' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1672)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.getBean(ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.java:78)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringRegistry$ConfigurableRegistrationDelegate.unregisterObject(SpringRegistry.java:433)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringRegistry.doUnregisterObject(SpringRegistry.java:260)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.registry.AbstractRegistry.unregisterObject(AbstractRegistry.java:146)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.unregisterObject(MuleRegistryHelper.java:474)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.registry.LegacyRegistryUtils.unregisterObject(LegacyRegistryUtils.java:122)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.safeUnregisterBean(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:643)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.lambda$createBeans$31(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:533)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.createBeans(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:517)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.lambda$createComponents$23(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:439)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:224)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:1075)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:993)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.createComponents(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:369)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.initializeComponents(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:343)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMuleArtifactContext.initializeComponents(LazyMuleArtifactContext.java:331)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.config.TestComponentLocator.initializeComponents(TestComponentLocator.java:63)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.model.builders.SuiteBuilder.build(SuiteBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunMessageHandler.buildSuite(RunMessageHandler.java:108)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunMessageHandler.parseSuiteMessage(RunMessageHandler.java:94)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunMessageHandler.parseAndRun(RunMessageHandler.java:81)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunMessageHandler.handle(RunMessageHandler.java:75)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer.handleClientMessage(RunnerServer.java:145)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.remote.api.server.RunnerServer.run(RunnerServer.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:113)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6697d772': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'EA10025-BTSNA-MOBILITYBTSNA-config' while setting bean property 'configuration'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'EA10025-BTSNA-MOBILITYBTSNA-config' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:314)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1672)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:346)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'EA10025-BTSNA-MOBILITYBTSNA-config' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:785)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.getBean(ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.java:78)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: Please add to the question your MUnit script and whatever is EA10025-BTSNA-MOBILITYBTSNA-config.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with an On-Prem project and referring the 'EA10025-BTSNA-MOBILITYBTSNA' configuration from domain project.

Create a new configuration for 'EA10025-BTSNA-MOBILITYBTSNA' in the same application for which you are writing the Munit.

And also generally this happens when your Runtime version is not compatible with Munit Version, I would suggest you to use an munit version which is compatible with your runtime. You can check the Release notes here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/munit/munit-release-notes